# Django raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use pyspark to preprocess data for the prediction model.
I get an error when I try spark.createDataFrame out of my preprocessing.Is there a way to check how processedRDD look like before making it to dataframe?

```
    import findspark
    findspark.init('/usr/local/spark')
    import pyspark
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import geohash2

    sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local', 'sentinel')
    spark = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)
    sql = SQLContext(sc)
    working_dir = os.getcwd()

    df = sql.createDataFrame(data)

    df = df.select(['starttime', 'latstart','lonstart', 'latfinish', 'lonfinish', 'trip_type'])
    df.show(10, False)
    processedRDD = df.rdd
    processedRDD = processedRDD \
                    .map(lambda row: (row, g, b, minutes_per_bin)) \
                    .map(data_cleaner) \
                    .filter(lambda row: row != None)
    print(processedRDD)
    featuredDf = spark.createDataFrame(processedRDD, ['year', 'month', 'day', 'time_cat', 'time_num', 'time_cos', \
                                              'time_sin', 'day_cat', 'day_num', 'day_cos', 'day_sin', 'weekend', \
                                              'x_start', 'y_start', 'z_start','location_start', 'location_end', 'trip_type'])
```

I am getting this error:

```
[Stage 1:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]2019-10-24 15:37:56 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)


raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
```

I do not understand what this have to do with importing an app

Comment: I don't even see where django is referred to in this script... What is `findspark`?

Comment: it something like a handle to use spark in my Django server so calculations can be done 10 times faster and cheaper

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what this script has to do with Django exactly, but adding the following lines at the top of the script will probably fix this issue:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
import django
django.setup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to load your settings and populate Django’s application registry before doing anything else. You have all the information required in the Django docs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manualy running Hadoop I am making a python server which is using pyspack and calculate 10 times faster heavy AI algorithms on Django server. The problem I had came from SPARK-LOCAL-IP, different IP was used (the one I use to connect to a remote database vis sshtunnel). I import and use pyspark. I had to rename a file and add the correct IP.

```
 cd /usr/local/spark/conf
 touch spark-env.sh.template
 mv -i spark-env.sh.template spark-env.sh
 nano spark-env.sh
 paste: SPARK-LOCAL_IP="127.0.1.1"
```

Then I had to add to my views.py sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")  To see what was the real problem .Debuging of java in python can be problematic sometimes. A column was datetime instead of string  and I fixed it.